# Visual Studio 2017 Typescript baseUrl/paths in tsconfig.json not being recognized

Tags: angular, visual-studio, typescript, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

I am using Visual Studio 2017 ASP.NET Core w/ Angular, however when I try to set baseUrl/paths Visual Studio is not recognizing the shortcuts.

Is this due to misconfiguration, or does Visual Studio 2017 not fully support this?

tsconfig.json:

```
"baseUrl": ".", 
"paths": {
  "@services/*": [ "ClientApp/app/shared/services/*" ] 
}
```

for the path I've also tried
"app/shared/services/*"

import declaration:

`import { MyService } from '@services/my.service';`

error:

> Cannot find module '@services/my.service

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nevermind, configuration error. The following was accepted and recognized by Visual Studio.

```
"baseUrl": "./ClientApp", 
"paths": {
  "@services/*": [ "app/shared/services/*" ]
}
```

Further to this the resolve section in webpack.config.js needs updating so that webpack also knows how to handle this alias.

```
resolve: {
    alias: {
        '@services': path.resolve(__dirname, 'ClientApp/app/shared/services')
    },
    extensions: ['.js', '.ts']
},
```

Comment: are you using webpack for this project?

Comment: FYI, you can use [`tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin`](https://github.com/dividab/tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin) instead of using `alias` (it reads your `tsconfig.json` file to generate the alias automatically).